# Python dictionary not getting updated

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I have below code where I am trying to add elements to a dict

```
for ent in NACLS:
    set_filter = {'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': [naclID]}
    print(set_filter)
    set_filter.update({'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': [str(ent[0])]})
    print(set_filter)
```

The output for the above code is

```
{'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': ['acl-08128a2540eb']}
{'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': ['50']}
{'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': ['acl-08128a2540eb']}
{'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': ['60']}
{'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': ['acl-08128a2540eb']}
{'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': ['70']}
```

Whereas I was wanting it to update the existing dictionary but somehow it's getting overwritten. Expected output

```
{'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': ['acl-08128a2540eb']}, {'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': ['50']}
{'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': ['acl-08128a2540eb']}, {'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': ['60']}
{'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': ['acl-08128a2540eb']}, {'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': ['70']}
```

can someone please guide me on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `update` method adds {`key`:`value`} pairs to a dictionary unless the key already exists, in which case it just updates the value to the new value.

From the look of your expected output it seems you want a list of dictionaries all with the same keys but different values.

try this:

```
set_filter = []
for ent in NACLS:
    set_filter.append({'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': [naclID]})
    set_filter.append({'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': [str(ent[0])]})
    print(set_filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what is the problem here. Do you want to print these dicts like you expected ?

You can write :

```py
for ent in NACLS:
    set_filter = {'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': [naclID]}
    print(set_filter,end=",")
    set_filter.update({'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': [str(ent[0])]})
    print(set_filter,end="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected output example isn't a valid dictionary:

```json
{'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': ['acl-08128a2540eb']}, {'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': ['50']}
```

Reformatted:

```json
{
    'Name': 'network-acl-id',
    'Values': [ 'acl-08128a2540eb' ]
},
{
    'Name': 'entry.rule-number',
    'Values': [ '50' ]
}
```

To create a list of dictionaries:

```py
for ent in NACLS:
    set_filter = [{'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': [naclID]}]
    #            ^ note square brackets                         ^
    print(set_filter)
    set_filter.append({'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': [str(ent[0])]})
    print(set_filter)
```

Or to put them all into a list:

```py
set_filter = []
for ent in NACLS:
    set_filter.append({'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': [naclID]})
    print(set_filter)
    set_filter.append({'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': [str(ent[0])]})
    print(set_filter)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I would want a list of dict

Comment: This is not an answer. Please ask questions for additional information in the comments!

Comment: Point taken @Klaus, it was temporarily half an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand much about your purpose of the list of dictionary, the suggested code

```py
set_filters = []
for ent in NACLS:
    set_filters.append({'Name': 'network-acl-id', 'Values': [naclID]})
    set_filters.append({'Name': 'entry.rule-number', 'Values': [str(ent[0])]})
```

is close to your idea. However, the two dictionaries you tried to gather in the list can be combined into just one:

```py
set_filters = []
for ent in NACLS:
    set_filters.append(
        {
            'network-acl-id': [naclID],
            'entry.rule-number': [str(ent[0])]
        }
    )
```

From here, you can make it shorter as

```py
set_filters = [
    { 'network-acl-id': [naclID], 'entry.rule-number': [str(ent[0])] } for ent in NACLS
]
```